# How to force docker-compose (standalone) on Podman to use buildah instead of buildx

Tags: docker, docker-compose, podman

I am running `docker-compose` with `podman` 4.4 as the container engine, on RHEL 8.  I have a containerfile that builds fine in any other configuration... straight podman, straight docker, docker-compose on Docker Engine, docker-compose on Docker Desktop.... but with this configuration it chokes on `RUN` commands to do `apt-get install` on an Ubuntu image.  A trivial example:

```
FROM ubuntu:lunar-20230615

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install vim --yes
```

Fails with this error:

```
4.817 Selecting previously unselected package vim.
4.817 Preparing to unpack .../23-vim_2%3a9.0.1000-4ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
4.820 Unpacking vim (2:9.0.1000-4ubuntu3.1) ...
4.852 dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-YHALEl/23-vim_2%3a9.0.1000-4ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
4.852  unable to install new version of './usr/share/bug/vim': Invalid cross-device link
4.865 Errors were encountered while processing:
4.865  /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-YHALEl/00-krb5-locales_1.20.1-1build1_all.deb
4.865  /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-YHALEl/01-libexpat1_2.5.0-1_amd64.deb
4.865  /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-YHALEl/02-libkrb5support0_1.20.1-1build1_amd64.deb
4.865  /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-YHALEl/03-libk5crypto3_1.20.1-1build1_amd64.deb
4.865  /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-YHALEl/04-libkeyutils1_1.6.3-2_amd64.deb
4.865  /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-YHALEl/05-libssl3_3.0.8-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
4.865  /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-YHALEl/06-libkrb5-3_1.20.1-1build1_amd64.deb
4.865  /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-YHALEl/07-libgssapi-krb5-2_1.20.1-1build1_amd64.deb
4.865  /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-YHALEl/08-libtirpc-common_1.3.3+ds-1_all.deb
4.865  /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-YHALEl/09-libtirpc3_1.3.3+ds-1_amd64.deb
4.865  /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-YHALEl/10-libnsl2_1.3.0-2build2_amd64.deb
4.865  /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-YHALEl/11-libpython3.11-minimal_3.11.4-1~23.04_amd64.deb
4.865  /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-YHALEl/12-media-types_10.0.0_all.deb
4.865  /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-YHALEl/13-readline-common_8.2-1.3_all.deb
4.865  /tmp/apt-dpkg-E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get install vim --yes" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

The following line also appears in `/var/log/messages`:

```
Aug 29 13:59:56 i-0be4cca766e4fd2e1 kernel: overlayfs: upper fs does not support xattr, falling back to index=off and metacopy=off.
```

This is noteworthy because my `containers/storage.conf` file uses `vfs` rather than `overlayfs`, so there should not be anything happening with overlayfs.

Ideally I would like `docker-compose` to use `podman/buildah` to build the containers, since I know that works.  It appears that docker-compose is creating a `buildx` container and using that to build the other containers, but what is going on in that `buildx` container or how to manipulate its configuration is quite opaque to me.

If I set DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0, `docker-compose` tries to use its legacy builder, but that gives me deprecation warnings and does not support `secrets` in the compose file.

I see in `docker compose build --help` that there is a `--builder` CLI flag available, but I cannot find any documentation as to what would constitute a valid use of this flag.

**ETA**: This doesn't actually help with my problem, but for anybody else who has this question, the `--builder` flag is meant to be set to the name of a builder created with `docker buildx create`, e.g.:

```bash
$ docker buildx create --name foo
$ docker compose build --builder foo my-service
```